# Fatal Error: The class 'AppBundle\Entity\Job' was not found Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

Hopefully you can help me.
Im working with symfony 3.4 on linux.
When i run my application i have the next error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: The class
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Job' was not found in the chain configured
>   namespaces in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:37
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php(112):
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces('AppBundle\Entit...',
>   Array) #1
>   /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(151):
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('AppBundle\Entit...',
>   Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #2
>   /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(332):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata),
>   NULL, false, Array) #3 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/
>   in /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Cache/Filesystem.php on
>   line 57

I created an entity named Job using the command

> php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity

It created without any problem the entity and the repository. 
After this I updated the database

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

So far so good. Now i start working with the controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Job;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $job = new Job();

        $job->setName('PHP');
        $job->setDescription('Description');
        $job->setCategory('IT');
        $job->setLocation('London');



        $em->persist($job);
        $em->flush();

        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If I try to dump $job before persisting the same, I get the result as

> object(AppBundle\Entity\Job)#242 (5) {
>   ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\Job":private]=>   NULL
>   ["name":"AppBundle\Entity\Job":private]=>   string(3) "PHP"
>   ["description":"AppBundle\Entity\Job":private]=>   string(11)
>   "Description"   ["category":"AppBundle\Entity\Job":private]=>
>   string(2) "IT"   ["location":"AppBundle\Entity\Job":private]=>
>   string(6) "London" } job

On the one hand, it says it cant find the Job class. On the other hand, it create the object well.

Anyone know what it is going on?

Tried

> php bin/console cache:clear 
>   php bin/console cache:warmup

Adding job class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Job
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="job")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\JobRepository")
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $location;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param string $category
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your AppBundle\Entity\Job class, please

Comment: Try clearing the cache.

Comment: Why have you used `base_dir` in render ?

Comment: Just a wild guess but I'm guessing you are trying to use annotations in some of your classes but you still have generated mapping file under Resources/config/doctrine

Comment: @SergeiKutanov Job class added to the main post. thanks for you help

Comment: Hi @Cerad. What do you mean exactly?. I am using annotation in my class (see the main post). I havent got AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine. I have AppBundle/Resources/doctrine/metadata/orm/Jobs.orm.xml
How can i fix it?

Comment: In Doctrine you can only use one type of mapping at a time (yaml,xml or annotation).  Completely remove the Resources/doctrine directory, clear your cache and see what happens.  Alternatively, remove the annotations from your entities.